# Angular2 Meteor execute function after data loading

Tags: meteor, angular, angular-meteor

How i can call function after cursor end loading?

on angular component i call data like

```
    var those = this;
    this.data= dataCollect.find({id: "1"});
    this.data.observe({
      added: function () {
        those.checkCountData();
      },
      changed: function () {
        those.checkCountData();
      },
      removed: function () {
        those.checkCountData();
      }
    });
```

where checkCountData is summ of property data.
But checkCountData call on each row added in progress loading
How i can call it one after load and on change\add\remove

Answer (score 0):

For 'after load':

You could `this.data.fetch()` to resolve the cursor's objects, the function is blocking I guess you can directly call `checkCountData()` after that.

For 'after add/change/remove':

Observe seems fine, you could create a `checkCountData` with 'add/change/remove' and 'data' argument that does not check/count all, but only does depending on the 'add/change/remove' context.

Regards